# Two images and two text lines lining up

Tags: html, css

I have two `<img>` and two `<p>` (basic caption text)

I want to format them in css to line up like this:

```
<img1>   <img2>
<text1>  <text2>
```

basically, two images with two captions under them.

I know this is fairly simple, but everything I have tried has not worked.

Comment: so what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty basic stuff:

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" />
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" />
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin:20px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PwKRT/)**

Essentially you wrap your image/text pairs in divs and float the divs left.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this way basically:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="images">
   <li>
       <img src="/path/to/img1" /><br/>
       <p>Your caption here</p>
   </li>
   <li>
       <img src="/path/to/img2" /><br/>
       <p>Your caption here</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.images{
  list-style-type:none;
}
.images li{
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.img-caption
{
float:left;
width:120px;
margin:0 0 15px 20px;
padding:15px;
border:1px solid black;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="img-caption">
<img src="image-name.gif" width="95" height="84" alt="" /><br>
CSS is fun!
</div>

<div class="img-caption">
<img src="image-name.gif" width="95" height="84" /><br>
CSS is fun!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```